# Search Date return no results

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a field say "DueDate" having a date/time data type. I create a view and include a search bar.  Now I want to search a specific date in a view that I created using the Search Bar but it returns 0 results.  What is the problem?  The date that I wanted to return exists in the view, but I got 0 results.  Any help please?

Comment: More specifics on what you are doing would be helpful here.

Comment: 1. I create a view and display the following information:

Comment: Submission   Version  DueDate

Comment: We assumed that the view consist a data already. In a view I added a button called Toggle Search. The Toggle Search will call the @Command([ViewShowSearchBar]) in order to show/hide the Search Bar. Now, the Search Bar ha been added to the view. I run the view and click on Toggle Search button. The Search Panel will show. I enter date on the textbox of the Search panel. Click the earh button of the Search Panel the result is 0. but the date is exist in the Duedate field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search bar is a powerful tool, but there is some inherent behaviour you should be aware of which is rarely explained. There is a syntax you can use as well to target your search. But firstly you should activate full-text indexing.

[Here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/6.5.1/help65_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/16a90676ed9ff9d385256dff00620f02?OpenDocument) are instructions on activating full-text indexing on a database.

You can search a specific field for date values among other things. There is a syntax associated for searching in Lotus Notes. For instance, referring to specific fields can be written as "[DueDate] = 01/01/2011" in the search bar. (Don't include the quotation marks.)

Check [this](http://www.nissan.gr/help/help85_admin.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/1fe816b545dde4b28525760b00049128?OpenDocument) link for search syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexed your database yet?

Comment: To create a full-text index, open the database from a Notes client and select File > Application > Properties... On the "magnifier" tab, use the Create Index button. You need to have Designer or Manager access to create the index.